What is the magic behind 'dataclass' decorator type-hint of dataclasses module?
I'm trying to deepen my understanding of how Python's dataclasses module works, particularly the role of type hints in defining class attributes.
When I define a dataclass like this:
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int

I notice that the type hints (str for name and int for age) are used by the dataclass decorator to generate various methods like __init__, __repr__, and __eq__ (I'm only interested in __init__). This automatic generation makes it very convenient, but I'm curious about the underlying mechanisms that enable this functionality.
Specifically, I have a question:
How does the dataclass decorator utilize type hints to generate these methods?
I’ve copied and pasted the same code from the original dataclasses file into my working directory with the name custom_dataclass (for testing purposes), but my linter did not recognize the __init__ attributes.

In picture1, you can see that when I try to instantiate the Person class, I correctly visualize all attributes mentioned in the Person class. This class uses the original @dataclass decorator. However, when I try the same with PersonCustom using the @custom_dataclass decorator, no attributes appear at all, as shown in picture2.

If anyone has any answers or insights, I’d like to hear them. Thanks in advance for your help!
I've also tried to see declarative_base method from sqlalchemy like
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    age = Column(Integer)


User()

but there no attributes appear either


Copying the dataclass source code into a custom_dataclass module only ensures that the runtime behaviour works. For static analysis, @dataclasses.dataclass is not expressible in standard Python annotations, and each type-checker implements special code analysis that runs separate to your Python runtime; see e.g. mypy (Python) and Pyright (TypeScript). @typing.dataclass_transform alleviates this somewhat.

I already notice that @typing.dataclass_transform is needed when I'm trying to create my constructor by my own.
Thank you so much for your answer!

Duplicate: How to annotate that a function produces a dataclass?.


[sqlalchemy] no attributes appear either

Well, there aren't any type hints involved.
Rather we're assigning Column objects to those names,
and each such object is storing a certain sql type
(not a hint, not an annotation).

the type hints ... are used by the dataclass decorator

Yes. It accesses them via an
API
call. Details are in the
documentation.
It appears your custom decorator is not making use of
dataclass_transform()
and is not doing work similar to what the
@dataclass
decorator does.
Which is unsurprising, as there's a lot of work involved,
at least when addressing the general case, about 1.5 KLOC of
source code.

First of all, thank you so much for your speedy response.
Regarding your answer, that's decorator solve my problem and I appreciate it so much. I'm intrigued as to how you found it though, due to in original code, there is no @dataclass_transform decorator reference anywhere.
Thanks again and happy coding!
